# Build a restapi in android from JSON

Tags: android, json, api, database-server

Suppose I have this json file

```
[{"item_id":"1000","item_name":"PEn","item_quantity":"2.66","item_rate":"3.69","item_purchase_date":"2020-05-13T00:00:00Z"},
{"item_id":"1004","item_name":"box","item_quantity":"63","item_rate":"20.5","item_purchase_date":"2020-06-12T00:00:00Z"}]
```

I want to make a rest api using this json file in Android. This json file should be locally available in my android device. When I send a certain request (**GET/DELETE/etc.**) to a certain URL (**localhost:3000/posts**), I want to perform requested operation.

Please show me how can I achieve this.

UPDATE 1: I don't need NanoHTTPD. (Its better if I can find something like golang with postgres)

Comment: What does it mean to make a REST API using a JSON file?  What do you mean by "perform requested operation"?

Comment: @RyanM "perform requested operation" means GET/DELETE/PUT/POST this operations.

Comment: @RyanM make a REST API using a JSON file, means I have some json data in a file. I can perform crud operation via api calls. [If you worked angular : this is the the exact tool i used, maybe there are similar tools also https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serve an api on an android device, you would need a webserver. The easiest way would be to extend a Java HTTP server and add your own logic.

Try [NanoHTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd), you can easily use it in android.